# Parse Server - Access to Parse Server using Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to access Parse Server (back4app.com) using Javascript SDK on my web app. I have `index.html` file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Javascript Parse SDK</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/parse@1.10.0/dist/parse.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

My Parse Server has **Program** class. And I want to retrieve one program named **Any Program**. My `app.js` file is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var Parse = require('parse');
    Parse.initialize('MY_APP_ID');
    Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/';

    var Program = Parse.Object.extend("Program");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Program);
    query.equalTo("name", "Any Program");
    query.find({
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
});
```

In my browser console, an error occurs:
[image]

I followed the documentation here: http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/

But no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm calling `require` in a web environment which doesn’t exist. I removed that line and added JS key. So my final `app.js` is like below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Parse.initialize('MY_APP_ID', 'JS_KEY');
    Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/';

    var Program = Parse.Object.extend("Program");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Program);
    query.equalTo("name", "Any Program");
    query.find({
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
});
```

It worked.